# Structure of database with questions and answers

Tags: database, database-design

I am designing a database that contains questions, answers and categories.

One question can belong to many categories, and one category can have many questions.
So this relationship is a many-to-many.

One question table
One category table
One table containing primary keys of the two tables above

So now my question is, is it necessary or "better" to store answers (a, b, c, d, e) in a own table named answers? Then the answer table has a foreign key to the primary key in the question table.

Or should I just have 5 columns in the question table containing the answers as well with the correct answer?

After what I read it is not normal to have a one - to - one relationship.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make a separate `answers` table. There are two benefits:

1. It fits in relational paradigm -- one question linked to many answers.
2. You will have flexibility, in case, if options for answers goes beyond 5.

---

The answers table should look like this:

```
ANSWERS
  answer_id (PK)
  answer_text
  is_correct
  serial_number
  question_id (FK)
```

Now, you store one answer in one row... and for serial_number (a,b,c.. or 1,2,3.. or i, ii, iii,... whatever) you use `serial_number` field.  `is_correct` points to correct answer/s.

You can select list of answers by

```
  select * from `answers` where question_id = 123 order by serial_number asc
```

Comment: thank you did some re-thinking and know I see why this is better and more flexible.

Comment: @Andreas Johannessen added more details

Comment: Yes, I saw it. Much appriciated, thank you! Now my database is ready:)

Answer (score 1):

If you know for certain that there will always be exactly give answers (neither more nor less), then it's reasonable to make them columns in the questions table.  It'll simplify your look-up process and be more efficient, generally.  However, if you sometimes have varying numbers of answers or might in the future, then your answers should have their own table.

Comment: Thanks, after a second thought I now see why this approach is better and more flexible.